# Exclude custom class from the css rule

Tags: css

I am trying to add a CSS rule for a href elements while excluding a certain class (.nolink)

```
.content a {
border-bottom: 2px;
}
```

I found that the **:not** selector could do just this but for some reason, I cannot use it properly.

So I have tried:

```
.content:not(.nolink) a {
border-bottom: 2px;
}
```

or

`.content:not('.nolink') a {
border-bottom: 2px;
}`

or

`.content a:not('.nolink') {
border-bottom: 2px;
}`

And some other minor edits but nothing seems to work properly. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the CSS code I use for the green hyperlink underline and hover that I am using on https://cbdhempoilusa.com where I want some elements to be discarded from this rule - those are the `.nolink` class elements.

Comment: Could we look at your HTML? Also, you must not add `'` around the selector in your `:not()` clause, so your first try is syntactically correct.

Comment: Tried adding the CSS code here but the question got "Closed" with this explanation:  `Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.` so I just added the website in question so you can see the code in action.

Comment: I'm not clinking a link to a website I don't know, sorry! The code must be in your question. If someone looks at your thread in 6 months and the site has changed, the URL is useless and the question won't give enough details to help others. Your question must always be self-contained. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,,, if need something else, pls let me know

```css
.content a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.content a:not(.noLink) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a class="content">anchor 1</a>
  <a class="content">anchor 1</a>
  <a class="content noLink">anchor 1</a>
  <a class="content">anchor 1</a>
  <a class="noLink content">anchor 1</a>
<div>
```

Comment: This is not the expected solution as I will have to "revert" every CSS rule I've initially set for the allowed class and this could be very frustrating when you have more than just the border-bottom rule. This is why I'm searching for a solution that will exclude the rule for the .nolink class from start. I will update my question with the real-life issue.